# Variavel PHP no HTML sem formulario

Tags: php

Tenho duas paginas 1ª HTMl e 2ª PHP onde estou tratando uns dados XML retornado após a leitura de um arquivo XML, porém estou com uma duvida besta, preciso pegar um valor que pego do XML e colocar dentro de uma tag html,  já fiz assim e nada

a pagina PHP está sendo chamada no HMTL(extensão dela e .php) pelo require_once.

TRECHO DO HTML

```
<table>
  <caption >Ti<?php echo $cnpj ?></caption>
  <tr>
    <td>John Lennon</td>
    <td>Rhythm Guitar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paul McCartney</td>
    <td>Bass</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>George Harrison</td>
    <td>Lead Guitar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ringo Starr</td>
    <td>Drums</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

TRECHO DO PHP

```
$arq = simplexml_load_file('29190411412201000112650010000000181000000180-nfe.xml') or die("Erro ao carregar arquivo XML");

foreach($arq->NFe->infNFe->children() as $infNFe){
$cnpj = $infNFe->CNPJ;

}
```

COMO CHAMAR UM VALOR DA VARIVEL DO PHP NA TAG HTML ?

Comment: Links para entender melhor o funcionamento do SOpt: [Tour], [Ask], [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70) e [Help]. [Edit] o post e reduzir o código a um [MCVE] pode ajudar bastante a viabilizar a pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com um simple ECHO :

test.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Nfe>
    <dados>
        <cliente>fulano</cliente>
        <cnpj>1234</cnpj>
    </dados>
</Nfe>
```

test.php

```
<?
$xmldata = simplexml_load_file("test.xml") or die("Failed to load");

$cnpj = $xmldata->dados[0]->cnpj;
$cliente = $xmldata->dados[0]->cliente;
?>


<h2> <? echo $cnpj; ?> </h2>
<h2> <? echo $cliente; ?> </h2>
```

Comment: Já fiz assim, mas nada acontece .

Comment: Renomea teu .html em .php

Comment: ja esta como .php a pagina que contem o HTML

Comment: Tu testou as variavel php ? $cnpj existe ?

Comment: Antes do foreach eu criei ela assim vazia $cnpj='';

Comment: Cria umphp assim, e test: <?

$cnpj = "11111111111";

?>


<h2> <? echo $cnpj; ?> </h2>

Comment: html --> <body>

<h1>TESTE <? echo $cnpj; ?></h1>

Comment: PHP -- $cnpj='1111111111111';

Comment: não funcionou, cara e mais facil ler uma arquivo XML pelo PHP ou usando Java script ?

Comment: Testei funciona muito bem !

Comment: O teste que eu te passei funciona ? Ou o problema e na hora de ler o xml ?

Comment: no caso com o foreach eu ja consigo ler o xml se eu der um echo dentro do foreach pegando as tags do XML funciona, mas quando eu atribuo a varial $cnpj ao resultado retornado da leitura do XML não consigo colocar pra aparecer na pagina, tipo assim estou lendo um XML processando com PHP e os dados processados quero fazer aparecer na pagina HTML

Comment: o teste que vc me passou não funcionou.

Comment: O `forEach` e dentro de uma function o do mesmo jeito que tu colocou na pergunta ?

Comment: sem function, do jeito que ta na pergunta.

Comment: No teu trecho de HTML tu não colocou os ; depois do $cnpj ==>  `<?php echo $cnpj; ?>`

Comment: coloquei -- ><h1>TESTE <? echo $cnpj; ?></h1>

Comment: Ok fiz um pequinho exemplo de test que funciona ! Da uma olhada !

Comment: No caso você pegou a leitura de um arquivo XML externo fez o processamento no PHP e na propria pagina PHP você ta imprimindo o resultado da leitura certo ?

Comment: sim ! exatamente ! E funciona!

Comment: Caraca, eu to fazendo o mesmo aqui e nada(vergonha), más obrigado você e fera, so mais uma coisa você sabe como ler um XML dessa mesma maneira com Java script ? se souber me manda um link pra referência.

Comment: Com Ajax : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlfile.asp